# Why 404 error through PHP cURL GET, but works fine in browser?

Tags: php, curl, http-status-code-404

StumbleUpon recently changed their framework and their API no longer works, so I'm trying to write a PHP script to access my Stumble history.

Embarrassingly enough, I'm stuck at the simple step of trying to GET the login page ;)

https://www.stumbleupon.com/login/ loads fine in my browser

But this PHP code displays a 404 page:

```
    // Vars
    $url = "https://www.stumbleupon.com/login/";
    $user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0";

    // Curl
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);     

    echo $response;
```

I've thought maybe they block certain user agents, so I've tried the same one my browser is using, but no luck.  I've also tried running the script from different IPs to eliminate an IP ban issue.  I'm really clueless on this one...very odd.

Any ideas?

Comment: They just don't want you to login using script. Respect their wishes

Comment: You are likely breaching their terms of service, @Kane. (And your user agent does not look too convincing ;).)

Comment: Thanks for the spanking guys, but I didn't post the question to get into an ethical debate ;)  If you don't have anything constructive to say...well you know how the saying goes...heh.  @middus - I've tried other user agents, including the exact one my browser uses, that's not the issue.

Comment: I get a 404 not found when I go to the given url (in browser)

Comment: What non-constructive in noticing that it is illegal? Illegal is bad, m'kay

Comment: @Kane How would you feel if I asked for advice on how to 'curl your mofo'? If you ask on how to do such a thing here, you'll have to accept that people will tell you what's wrong about it. (Same for, e.g., advice how to spam etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using https://www.stumbleupon.com/login.php instead. The URL you put returns a 404 for me to.

Comment: That's odd, in my browser StumbleUpon wants me to login to the new login page (/login), but when I try the same process via PHP it is showing the old page (/login.php) and the new page gives a 404.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 2):

They could be looking for some other HTTP header. You should try seeing what your browser does when it requests this page with something like `live http headers` and try to incorporate one HTTP header at a time into your script and see which one solves your issue.